# Android SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, null

I'm a beginner android programmer. I have a problem and can't solve it. I want to add the wallet to the database, but the application throws me an error.
It seems that it takes the value of the EditText.  Whats wrong?

I have error:

```
    Error inserting currency=null surname=null start_acc=0.0 name=null
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_dodawanie_portfela"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.xxx.xxx.xxx">

    <TextView
        android:text="xxx"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:text="xxx"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:text="xxx"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:text="xxx"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView6" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
        android:id="@+id/curenncy" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/curenncy"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/curenncy"
        android:id="@+id/name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name"
        android:id="@+id/surname" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/curenncy"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/curenncy"
        android:id="@+id/cash" />

    <Button
        android:text="ADD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addwallet"
        android:width="500dp"
        android:background="@color/common_action_bar_splitter"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Method

```
 public void AddWallet(String name, String surname, int start_acc, int curenncy){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Wallets.COLUMNS.name, wallet.getName());
    contentValues.put(Wallets.COLUMNS.surname, wallet.getSurname());
    contentValues.put(Wallets.COLUMNS.start_acc, wallet.getStart_acc());
    contentValues.put(Wallets.COLUMNS.curenncy, wallet.getCurrency());
    DbHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert(Wallets.NAME_TABLE,null,contentValues);
}
```

Class

```
public class Add extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText name;
EditText surname;
EditText start_acc;
Button add;
Spinner curenncy;

int id_value;
DatabaseDEO db = new DatabaseDEO(this);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    surname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.surname);
    start_acc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cash);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addwallet);
    curenncy = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.curenncy);


    curenncy.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            id_value = position;

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


    final ArrayList<String> list= db.getToSpinner();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.currency_spinner, R.id.text,list);
    curenncy.setAdapter(adapter);



    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String pname = name.getText().toString();
            String psurname = surname.getText().toString();
            int pstart_acc = Integer.parseInt(start_acc.getText().toString());
            int pid_value = id_value;

            db.AddWallet(pname,psurname,pstart_acc,pid_value);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: one of your columns doesn't accept null values but you are getting null value from edit text. make sure you enter something in edittext. You should also check for null before inserting the data.

Comment: Yes, one column have not null atribute, but I wirte text in edittext and choose options in spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Above code to this and it will work. I guess you were taking values from some model class object wallet but you were not setting them.

```
public void AddWallet(String name, String surname, int start_acc, int curenncy){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Wallets.COLUMNS.name, name);
    contentValues.put(Wallets.COLUMNS.surname, surname);
    contentValues.put(Wallets.COLUMNS.start_acc, start_acc);
    contentValues.put(Wallets.COLUMNS.curenncy,curenncy);
    DbHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert(Wallets.NAME_TABLE,null,contentValues);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Work! But I can't get ID curenncy from spinner. 
Maybe you know how to do it? Method   curenncy.setOnItemSelectedListener must be called?

Comment: @Adrien Why you are storing spinner position in database? You should store selected item value in it.  You can use curenncy.getSelectedItem().toString(); And if you have integer value, you can parse it to int.

Comment: In database I have table Curenncy, where is id_curenncy and code_currency columns. Spinner value is from database (data from code_currency column). I want get id_currency, which user choose.

Comment: @Adrien you should try reading spinner documentation here to get clear picture about spinners. It is not as though as you are making them.

Comment: Previously you wrote about the lack of set values. I tried to do it. But I have a problem. You know how it should look like?